# How to get the content of table after a keyword in Microsoft Word using Python

Tags: python, excel, docx, xlsxwriter, python-docx

I have many paragraphs and many tables in a Microsoft Word file. I need to get the content of the table after the specified keyword in paragraph using Python.

How should I write my code? I tried to use docx package in Python, but the syntax is docx.tables[2]. But I could not identify which index of table is that, I need to find the table by the keyword before it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel?

Comment: Hi @SolarMike I need to find the table in Microsoft word located after a keywordd

Comment: So, are you doing this with Excel?